ESXI vSphere cannot set CD/DVD drive to "Connect after power On"
some time ago I was troubleshooting how to add passthrough PCI device to VM, in vSphere 7.0 (ESXi) Since that , I am unable to "Install VMWare tools" to any VMs (even those I did not touch)
I have found out, that to make the "Install VMware tools" need under "CD/DVD drive" to be set to "CLIENT DEVICE" and have the "Connect after power on" activated....The issues is that this checkbox "Connect after power on" is disabled/greyed out. See image.
Other modes (Host device, Datastore ISO, etc) has this option checkable, just the crucial "Client device" not.
Any ideas? (ESXi 6.5, vSphere 7, all VMs and install VMware tools used to be OK-it doesnt help if CD/DVD is removed, or if VM is started or not...still same)
Thank you in advance.

I have found out, that to make the "Install VMware tools" need under "CD/DVD drive" to be set to "CLIENT DEVICE" and have the "Connect after power on" activated - I've never heard or read that anywhere and have never found that to be the case.


Other modes (Host device, Datastore ISO, etc) has this option checkable, just the crucial "Client device" not.

Because the VM can boot without a remote console attached, it can't be set to connect client device (which is a local device on the remote console host).

, I am unable to "Install VMWare tools" to any VMs (even those I did not touch) I have found out, that to make the "Install VMware tools" need under "CD/DVD drive" to be set to "CLIENT DEVICE" and have the "Connect after power on" activated...

The documentation doesn't mention this, nor has it ever been required in my use of ESXi. The VM is required to have a CD-ROM device attached, but whatever iso is currently in use will simply be swapped for the VMWare image, and the device mounted.

So what else could be the reason, that "Install VM ware tools" is greyed out on all VMs now? (No matter if on or off the vm is, ) ...

The ISO images are not present on the host, the OS is not supported (or correct version selected), or vmware belives latest tools is installed for instance.

Hi, thanks, If A. ISO images are not present : How can I locate the iso image and double check it is there? B. If OS is not supported : It used to work some time ago, where this could be set? C. VmWare believes latest tools is installed : If I had latest VMWare tools installed previously, even then it was possible to Install Vmware tools again (if I remember it correctly) ...so this is not the case I guess,....
